# Access to my ubuntu server with a public ip address

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, apache2

I have a problem with my raspberry pi 4 model B 4Go
I have installed Ubuntu Server 21.10
And installed apache2
And I have a basic ssh access
I can access it (ssh and web) with its local ip (192.168.1.90)
However impossible to connect or to load a web page with its public ip address, firewall of my pc all closed.
I don't understand the problem because before on my computer with Wamp installed, lowering the firewall and loading an apache page with a public ip was totally possible (by retesting just now it works without any problem)
I also opened port 80 on my box for testing and still nothing

Is there anything else to configure on my box or directly on my server?
Thanks

```
<Directory />
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
      Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
      AllowOverride None
      Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride None
      Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#     AllowOverride None
#     Require all granted
#</Directory>
```

Here the part of the content in etc/apache/apache2.conf but I don't think it's that since I can't connect anywhere with this ip

Comment: Are you using a router in front of your PC or are you connecting via an internal/usb WAN 3G module?

Comment: My rasberry is connected in ethernet to the box but I am in wifi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to complete my problem thanks to the "port forwarding" option on my box and not the firewall, it is enough to redirect the ports 80 to its local ip, I did not know at all that this option existed. It is possible to do it with all ports. The firewall doesn't seem to influence this, thanks to you

Comment: the answer is better suited as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The apache configuration is correct.
Can you check and upload the `/var/log/apache2/error.log` file of apache to check what is the error?
Run the `tail -f` command on the log and refresh the web by accessing the public IP.

It is possible that your router is blocking the traffic.
Have you opened the ports?

---

Edit;
There is an error in the image, the open port has to be redirected to a local IP. The router does not know where to send the traffic.
There is a mistake in the picture, you have to redirect the open port to an IP. The router does not know where it has to send the traffic.

Comment: I have several clues from what you told me to do. 
I have nothing in the error log file, it's from another time and it's related to commands from me
But with curl if i run the command "curl (public ip)" i have the error "curl : (7) Failed to connect to 89.xx180.xxx port 80 : Connection refused"

Comment: i had tried to open port like this (sorry the panel is in french)
https://ibb.co/1r97LR1
but doesnt seem work

Comment: There is an error in the image, the open port has to be redirected to a local IP. The router does not know where to send the traffic.
There is a mistake in the picture, you have to redirect the open port to an IP. The router does not know where it has to send the traffic.